# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' помогите разобраться!)

Tags: python, tkinter

Код идиотки, но помогите все же разобраться. В основном проблема заключается в переводе str в int. Облазила интернет, что то подправила, но все равно ошибки растут как на грибах. Именно сейчас invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''. Укажите на ошибки и скажите что подправить...

```
 import tkinter

def click():
    label.config(text=tc)

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry('250x150')
frame1 = tkinter.Frame(window)
frame1.pack()
label1 = tkinter.Label(frame1, text='Калькулятор Цельсий-Фаренгейт')
label1.pack()

frame3 = tkinter.Frame(window)
frame3.pack()
entry = tkinter.Entry(frame3)
entry.pack()
ConvertToInt= int(entry.get())
a = ConvertToInt
label = tkinter.Label(frame3)
label.pack()
tc = (5/9*(a-32))
button = tkinter.Button(frame3, text='Click', command=click)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите эти несколько строк в функцию

```
def click():
    ConvertToInt= int(entry.get())
    a = ConvertToInt
    tc = (5 / 9 * (a - 32))

    label.config(text=tc)
```

Comment: Вуф, спасибо помогло)